# Generating function of binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, binomial-coefficients

We want to evaluate the sum $$\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}L(L+1)x^L$$

From [this set of notes](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~faris/combinatoricsweb/generate.pdf) (page 2, equation 8) we find the formula $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}y^n = \frac{y^n}{(1-y)^{n+1}}$$ which suggests that I can do $$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}\binom{L+1}{2}x^{L+1} = \frac{x^L}{(1-x)^{L+2}}\tag{1}\label{eqn1}$$ since $$\frac{1}{2}L(L+1) = \frac{(L+1)!}{2!((L+1)-2)!}$$

But if I do 
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}L(L+1)x^L & = \sum_{L=0}^{\infty}\frac{L}{2}\frac{d}{dx}x^{L+1} \\ 
& = \sum_{L=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} \left[(L+2)x^{L+1} - 2x^{L+1}\right] \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \sum_{L=0}^{\infty} x^{L+2} - \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{L=0}^{\infty} x^{L+1} \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \frac{x^2}{1-x} - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{1-x} \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} \left[2x(1-x)^{-1} + x^2(1-x)^{-2}\right] - \left[(1-x)^{-1} + x(1-x)^{-2}\right] \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{2x-x^2}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{x}{1-x} \right] - \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \left[(1-x)^{-2} + 2x(1-x)^{-3} \right] \\
& = \frac{1+x}{2(1-x)^3}
\end{aligned}

which is nowhere close to (1). Where did I go wrong?

All help is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure the formula to get (1) is right? There seems to be something fishy there. How can a formula summed over n depend on n, if it's going all the way till infinity?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure...that formula came from lecture notes (as linked in the post) for a Math module taught in Arizona University. Wikipedia, on the other hand, on the page "Binomial coefficient" under section 8 "Ordinary generating functions" states instead that the formula is $$\frac{y^k}{(1-y)^{k+1}}$$ but unfortunately does not appear to cite the source.

Comment: That seems more like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:*   The cited formula (8) is not correct. There is a typo since we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}y^n = \frac{y^{\color{blue}{k}}}{(1-y)^{\color{blue}{k+1}}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We  therefore   expect
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x}\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}\binom{L+1}{2}x^{L+1} =\frac{1}{x}\sum_{L=1}^{\infty}\binom{L}{2}x^L
= \frac{x^{\color{blue}{1}}}{(1-x)^{\color{blue}{3}}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> Your derivation is fine  up to
>   \begin{align*}
>  \frac{d}{dx}& \frac{2x-x^2}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\left((2-2x)(1-x)^{-2}+(2x-x^2)(+2)(1-x)^{-3}\right)-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{2x-x^2}{(1-x)^3}\right)-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{x}{(1-x)^3}}
> \end{align*}
>
> in  accordance with (2).

*Hint:*  With respect  to  (1)   we   have
\begin{align*}
\frac{y^k}{(1-y)^{k+1}}&=y^k\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-(k+1)}{n}(-y)^n\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{k+n}{n}y^{n+k}\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{n-k}y^n=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{n}{k}y^n\tag{5}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k}y^n\tag{6}
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (5) we shift the index to start with $n=k$.
- In (6) we use $\binom{p}{q}=0$ if $q>p$.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, a simpler way would to consider

$$S=\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}L(L+1)x^L\implies T=2S=\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}L(L+1)x^L$$
$$T=\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}L(L-1+2)x^L=\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}L(L-1)x^L+2\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}Lx^L$$

$$T=x^2\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}L(L-1)x^{L-2}+2x\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}Lx^{L-1}$$
$$T=x^2 \left(\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}x^{L} \right)''+2x \left( \sum_{L=0}^{\infty}x^{L}\right)'$$